# PlayFramework render multiply views for a one html page

Tags: java, scala, templates, view, playframework-2.2

I would like to generate an HTML page using Play Framework. For this page I would like use two views templates. Each generated/rendered separately, and glued into one.

I ask for this particular functionality, because I have many views that I would like to reuse in different combinations. I would like to avoid to paste them all into one template, and use if statements to generate the correct view.

This views are not related to each other, and they are too huge (about 1000 lines each) to be all in one file, so I decided to split them.

I know that I can inject one view into another. This is what I do for many cases (eg. I inject `currentView.scala.html` into `mainManuView.scala.html`), but in this particular case it is not a really an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `render(...).body` to get the HTML content of every view and concatenate them together.

```
val partOne = views.html.partOne.render(...).body
val partTwo = views.html.partTwo.render(...).body
Ok(partOne + partTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way that I've figure out later on my own, is to call view with parameters as a normal method from other view.

Example view:

```
@(header: String, variable1: String, variable2: String, sharedVariable: String)
@MainManuView(header) {
    <div>
        @views.html.partOneView(variable1, sharedVariable)
    </div>
    <div>
        @views.html.partTwoView(variable2, sharedVariable)
    </div>

}
```